# Gigolo/gnome password safety

Tags: 12.04, gnome, password, gigolo

I was proposed to save a password in gnome-shell @ 12.04 using Gigolo:

[image]

Where exactly are these passwords saved and how are they encrypted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gigolo doesn't store the password itself, rather it uses `gnome-keyring` to store them. Following is the quote from [Gigolo's Help Document](http://www.uvena.de/gigolo/help.html#storing-passwords-for-bookmarks)

> There is no support for direct storing of passwords at all in Gigolo. Instead by using `GVfs` we get support for `gnome-keyring` for free. All you have to do is to install the `gnome-keyring` package (and maybe restart your session). The next time you connect to a resource which requires a password, Gigolo will ask you for it as usual and then the entered password is stored in the keyring for this connection. Currently, your password is stored forever. This will be configurable in future versions to store it only per session or to not store it at all.

Now coming to [GnomeKeyring](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring):

1. **Where does it stores the passwords?**

   It stores the password in `keyrings` folder:

   - In Ubuntu 12.10, it is located at `~/.local/share/keyrings/`
   - In Ubuntu 12.04 and earlier, it is located at `~/.gnome2/keyrings/`
2. **How are these passwords encrypted?**

   Quoting from [GnomeKeyring's Security FAQs](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring/SecurityFAQ#Which_cryptographic_algorithms_are_used.3F):

   > [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) for hashing, [AES-128](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) for encrypting the secrets.